# Unexpected "unchecked conversion" warning

Tags: java, generics, java-6, unchecked

The following code results in an unchecked conversion compiler warning -

```
{
    List<String> first = first((Class)Integer.class);
}

private <T> List<String> first(Class<T> clazz) { return null; }
```

However, the following code doesn't have any warnings -

```
{
    List<String> second = second((Class)Integer.class);
}

private List<String> second(Class<?> clazz) { return null; }
```

There are three warnings in total, the first two I expect but the third doesn't make sense -

```
$ javac Test1.java -Xlint
    Test1.java:6: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
    found   : java.lang.Class
    required: java.lang.Class<T>
    List<String> first = first((Class)Integer.class);
                               ^
    Test1.java:6: warning: [unchecked] unchecked method invocation: <T>first(java.lang.Class<T>) in Test1 is applied to (java.lang.Class)
    List<String> first = first((Class)Integer.class);
                              ^
    Test1.java:6: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
    found   : java.util.List
    required: java.util.List<java.lang.String>
    List<String> first = first((Class)Integer.class);
                              ^
    3 warnings
```

Compiler version -

```
$ javac -version
    javac 1.6.0_45
```

My question is, why does the third compiler warning occur?

Comment: The first code sample generates compiler warning. The second one (very similar) doesn't. I guess we need Sherlock to guess what the question is here...

Comment: My guess is that passing in a raw type, `Class` (instead of, say, `Class<?>` or `Class<Integer>`), is invalidating the `<T>` in the signature of the `first` method, and for some reason that causes the entire method call to be treated as a raw invocation.  Thus, it not only invalidates `<T>` but also the `<String>` in the return type.

Comment: Try removing `<T>` from the first piece of code ---`private <T> List<String> first(Class<T> clazz) { return null; }`

Comment: @VGR right you are, I looked in to that further and found this -
http://snipurl.com/unchecked
I'm new to Stackoverflow so not really sure how this works... do you want to make your comment a full response so I can mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're passing parameters using the pre-generic (raw)

```
first((Class)Integer.class)
```

instead of

```
first((Class<?>)Integer.class)
```

the return type of `first` is downgraded to the pre-generic `List` instead of `List<String>`, and using `List` where `List<String>` is expected results in an unchecked conversion warning.

---

The Java documentation on [Raw Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) explain:

> Raw types show up in legacy code because lots of API classes (such as the Collections classes) were not generic prior to JDK 5.0. When using raw types, you essentially get pre-generics behavior — a Box gives you Objects. **For backward compatibility, assigning a parameterized type to its raw type is allowed:**
>
> ...
>
> But if you assign a raw type to a parameterized type, you get a warning:

Comment: Seems like the (whole) generics is turned off for that invocation. +1

Comment: @BheshGurung, Yes.  For backwards compatibility, any type derived from an operator which takes a raw type as input must result in a raw type or an ungeneric type.  This is so that libraries can have generics added while pre-generic (and possibly type-unsound) client code still compiles against them just fine.  Piecemeal migration of projects was a high priority when generics were first introduced.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that passing in a raw type, `Class` (instead of, say, `Class<?>` or `Class<Integer>`), is invalidating the `<T>` in the signature of the `first` method, and for some reason that causes the entire method call to be treated as a raw invocation.  Thus, it not only invalidates `<T>` but also the `<String>` in the return type.